# How do I pass a variable to the kbd function?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I have the following snippet:

```
(setq evil-string-inflection-bind "g~")
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd evil-string-inflection-bind) 'evil-operator-string-inflection)
```

The above snippet will not work.

Now I know for a fact that this works:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g~") 'evil-operator-string-inflection)
```

Why the first snippet does not work while the second does? At first look, they should be equal.

Is there a way to pass arguments to the `(kdb)` function or is it special somehow?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're trying to do in general.  I can't replicate your problem in 26.1 (albeit not using `evil` specifically).  *Exactly* what do you mean when you say "The above snippet will not work" ?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?  IIRC `kbd` was a macro in the past, which could account for the problem.  Does `C-h f kbd` say that it's a function or a macro?

Comment: @phils I mean that I cannot solve [this](https://github.com/ninrod/evil-string-inflection/issues/3) issue because nothing is bound to my text-object. Using the second snippet, it works but it does not solves the issue. I'm using latest emacs from archlinux, which is 26.1

Comment: kbd is a function in emacs 26.1, which is my case.

Comment: It all sounds rather specific to `evil` then.  I've added the tag accordingly, and hopefully someone else who uses it will be better placed to answer this.

Comment: It might be that you need to ask a different question, though.  I've posted an answer which suggests to me that your issue is not as generic as you initially thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think your stated question is perhaps not related to your problem.  It sounds rather specific to `evil`.  Certainly we can see that there is no fundamental difference between passing a string literal to `kbd` and passing a variable with that same value:

```
ELISP> emacs-version
"26.1"

ELISP> (setq map1 (make-sparse-keymap))
ELISP> (define-key map1 (kbd "g~") 'evil-operator-string-inflection)
ELISP> map1
(keymap
 (103 keymap
      (126 . evil-operator-string-inflection)))

ELISP> (setq map2 (make-sparse-keymap))
ELISP> (setq evil-string-inflection-bind "g~")
ELISP> (define-key map2 (kbd evil-string-inflection-bind) 'evil-operator-string-inflection)
ELISP> map2
(keymap
 (103 keymap
      (126 . evil-operator-string-inflection)))
```